# pre-populated emails

Tags: email, email-template, outlook

Please see the initial sketch below.
Can you please tell me if this is possible in Salesforce, or if there is a better way of doing this?
Would I have to use Outlook? or can this be done directly within salesforce?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done directly in Salesforce using macros: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/service-cloud-agent-productivity/create-a-macro-and-quick-text. Requires lightning, which from the image above you appear to be using, and some additional configuration.